# Выход из многоуровневого цикла

Tags: java, циклы

Есть ли в java универсальный способ выйти из многоуровневого цикла? Или же необходимо составлять грамотное условие для каждого уровня? 
Например:

```
for( ... ){
    while( ... ){
        ...
        break(2); // не обращайте внимания
    }
}
```

Я думаю, вы поняли, что я имею в виду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, вам поможет лэйбл

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    outerloop:
    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j < 5; j++) {
        if (i * j > 6) {
          System.out.println("Breaking");
          break outerloop;
        }
        System.out.println(i + " " + j);
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
  }
}
```

---

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 0
2 1
2 2
2 3
Breaking
Done
```